# MySQL: Convert INT to DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a UNIX-type timestamp stored in an `INT` column in MySQL.  What is the proper way to retrieve this as a MySQL `DATETIME`?

*(I found the answer when re-scanning the MySQL Date functions, but didn't see the answer on SO. Figured it should be here.)*

Answer (score 108, accepted):

[`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Answer (score 43):

```
select from_unixtime(column,'%Y-%m-%d') from myTable;
```

Comment: ahhhh...  but the time :)    Sometimes we want it, including as stated by OP

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(mycolumn)
FROM    mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [STR_TO_DATE(COLUMN, '%input_format')](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) can do it, you only have to specify the input format.
Example : to convert p052011

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('p052011','p%m%Y') FROM your_table;
```

The result : **2011-05-00**

Answer (score 0):

This works for sure.

```
select from_unixtime(column) from table
```