# Trouble Converting varchar to date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I'm using MAMP's phpMyAdmin as my database.
I'm having troubles using the CONVERT sql function. Is this a common problem?

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), Date, 103)
```

This will give me the following syntax error. Which is one of the usual errors given but I've been trying a lot of different ways.

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'varchar(10), Date, 103)' at line 1**

If the above can't be solved can I bypass this issue by adding a new column with a specific date format style?

Comment: You're using SQL Server Syntax (T-SQL) in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The date is already in the correct format but it is stored as `varchar(10)` Current looks like: `21/04/2014`*
>
> *Yes, I have a column that has dates but is set to varchar as it wasn't being used now I need to convert these into dates.*

If you are trying to get a date form from a string form of date, then

```
select str_to_date( date_column, '%d/%m/%Y' ) as date from table_name
```

This will return `21/04/2014` as `2014-04-21`, regular default date format in `MySQL`.

Comment: Thanks, perfect anyway that I can keep the same date format?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) syntax in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) database.

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) does not have 3rd parameter for `CONVERT` function.

> CONVERT(expr,type), CONVERT(expr USING transcoding_name)
>
> The CONVERT() and CAST() functions take an expression of any type and
>   produce a result value of a specified type.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

to do the get same format in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) you need to use `DATE_FORMAT()` function

this should give you the same result`DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y')`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
 select DATE_FORMAT(Current_Date(),'%d/%m/%Y')
```

here is SQL Fiddle 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/36014

Comment: What about converting a whole column's datatype?

Comment: in that case you need `str_to_date` function.. see @Ravinder's answer

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do.

If you're trying to convert an integer that represents a Unix timestamp to a date with MySQL, you may want to use [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

See also: [MySQL: Convert INT to DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367603/mysql-convert-int-to-datetime)

If you're trying to convert a string that represents a date into a date, you can use [STR_TO_DATE()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)

After that, if you perform some processing on the date and want to convert it back to a string, you'll need [DATE_FORMAT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

See also: [mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)

Comment: The date is already in the correct format but it is stored as varchar(10) Current looks like: 21/04/2014

Comment: @SitRock: Are you trying to get a `date` form from a `string` form of date?

Comment: Yes, I have a column that has dates but is set to varchar as it wasn't being used now I need to convert these into dates.

Comment: @SitRock: then you may want to use something like this... `date_format(str_to_date('21/04/2014', '<here your input date format>'), '<here your output date format>');`  See the reference http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/