# Delete rows from MySQL table where date field is two weeks or older

Tags: mysql, date, delete-row

I am having to go through someone else's code on a Perl script that updates a MySQL table with any new records and is supposed to also delete from the table any records where the reporting date is two weeks or older.  Currently, the script does not have a date field for the reporting date, but instead is an integer field (not sure why it was done this way).  The Perl script calls a .sql file which is supposed to take care of the delete, but it is not working.

Which would be easier to work with?  Leave it an integer field or change it to a date field and change his sql statement for reflect that?

Here is the current delete statement, if that helps (a bit way too complex for me to tackle yet) -

```
DELETE FROM Spectros
WHERE
    (spectroReportDt LIKE CONCAT(MONTH(CURDATE()),
        '%',
        DAY(CURDATE()) - 14,
        YEAR(CURDATE()))

        OR spectroReportDt LIKE CONCAT(MONTH(CURDATE()) - 1,
        '%',
        DAY(CURDATE()) + 14,
        YEAR(CURDATE()))

        OR spectroReportDt LIKE CONCAT(MONTH(CURDATE()) + 11,
                '%',
        DAY(CURDATE()),
        YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1))

    AND (CAST(SUBSTR(spectroReportDt, LENGTH(MONTH(CURDATE())) + 1, 2) AS UNSIGNED) <= DAY(CURDATE()) - 14

                OR CAST(SUBSTR(spectroReportDt, 1, LENGTH(MONTH(CURDATE()))) AS UNSIGNED) != MONTH(CURDATE()))
```

and the reportDate field is MMDDYYYY in the text file from which it updates and in the MySQL table - except there are no leading zeros on one digit months in the records, since it's an integer.

Comment: Either: just use built in functions... you could use the from_UnixTime to convert... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367603/mysql-convert-int-to-datetime  assuming it is a unix_time... or use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to convert your date to the interger that can be compared.  Be sure to read the notes:...

Comment: Maybe it's an unix timestamp....

Comment: Could be written as good in Brainf*ck ;-)

Comment: These dates are just plain *bad*. Do anything you can to turn these into SQL-standard `DATE` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `DATE` field for that column, and you *should* be, then you can do this using [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub):

```
DELETE FROM Spectros WHERE spectroReportDt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

If you're doing this on a large table you'll want to have your date field indexed so that this isn't painfully slow.

If you've got the date stored in some other format you may need to convert here. `MMDDYYYY` format is ugly, non-standard, and a pain because it can't be sorted on. Flipping that to ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD` would help *considerably*.

You can convert on the fly using this:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(spectroReportDt, '%m%d%Y') < DATE_SUB(...)
```

That requires a heavy-duty table scan, so it's less than ideal. If you've got a problem with leading zeroes, you might need to format that first:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(LPAD(spectroReportDt, 8, 0), '%m%d%Y') < DATE_SUB(...)
```

Comment: This helps tremendously, thank you.  And the table is only about 3,900 records, so should not be long to run.