# phpmyadmin: how to convert int to date?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The existing database uses int to store the date information
[image]

That makes sql queries quite harder to write and to view:

**->is there a way to say to phpmyadmin: keep the int format, but display it like a date for sql results ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Convert INT to DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367603/mysql-convert-int-to-datetime)

Comment: you can that type format to varchar(255) and you can store date as your format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

ALTER TABLE table_name

MODIFY COLUMN deadline DATE,

MODIFY COLUMN deadline_updated_by DATE,

MODIFY COLUMN deadline_updated_by DATE,

Comment: This will change the data, but will most likely lose all the data in the respective column, as mysql will try to convert from INT to DATE, without knowing its a timestamp. A better approach would be to create a new column, copy over the data from the old column as DATE, so you can verify the data, and then drop the old columns

Comment: no i have first tried on my existing table .no data will be loss

Comment: How is this the accepted answer, when it doesn't even answer the question? The question was how to change the display format in phpmyadmin WITHOUT changing the column type.